# Require()'ing a Class to use in Inheritance

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance

I just have a simple question here... I was working on developing a forum application for my website, and while updating some of the old methods I used (my old code is horrid) I came across - not for the first time - OOP devices.

I have quite a few classes that my system uses, and redefining the same function(s) for them over and over, so I decided to create a base class that would carry the functionality.

I've been trying to use `require()` on the base class then extend the class off of it...

```
<?php
require(//path to base class);

class User extends BaseClass {
// code
}
?>
```

But I don't know how to check if it's there, and it doesn't seem to be inheriting the base class's only function...

```
public function __get($what) {

if(property_exists($this, $what)) {

return $this->{$what};

} else {

return null;

}

}
```

Since when I try to retrieve a variable from the User class (e.g. `$user->Username`) it returns `NULL`. The variable is marked as `private` in the class, but before I tried to do inheritance that wasn't an issue.

Comment: If `require` fail to add you file, it will stop the script anyway, isn't it ? What is the problem ? You're not sure that BaseClass is in the file you are require'ing ?

Comment: Well, I suppose to make it clearer my problem is what I mentioned at the end; the __get I defined in BaseClass isn't working like it had when I just defined it in User. I'm not sure if it's because it doesn't work in inheritance, or if there's something wrong with inheriting from a require()'d class.

Comment: I suspect you have a variable $Username in your BaseClass? Then you should make it protected. Private variables are only visible to the actual class, protected are visible for extending classes as well.

Comment: @Splashsky The problem is not about `require` at least

Comment: @user3535256 that actually makes sense. And no, all the variables are in User, the only thing BaseClass has is the `__get` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to get after your variables in your parent class but do not want to use getter methods to do so.  Marking these variables `protected` will indeed allow your child classes access to those properties, but in cases where you want your base class to enforce processing before setting/getting, marking the properties `protected` will not cut it.

In your case it sounds like you are marking your variables `protected` as a workaround.  However you can still use `private` variables in your base class and allow access to them in your child classes as follows:

```
class BaseClass
{
    private $strValue = "We the people....";

    public function __get($what)
    {
        if(isset($this->{$what})) {
            return $this->{$what};
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    private $intValue = 255;

    public function __get($what)
    {
        if(isset($this->{$what})) {
            return $this->{$what};
        } else if(parent::__get($what) != null) {
            return parent::__get($what);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//Try it out
$child = new ChildClass();
var_dump($child->strValue); //"We the people...."
var_dump($child->intValue); //255
```

In this example the `BaseClass` uses the `__get()` magic method to lookup its own properties and the `ChildClass` overrides it to do the same.  In the `ChildClass` if it cannot find a requested property, then it diverts to the parent's version.

As long as you don't override your properties you can use private variables throughout and access them *as if* they were public outside of your class scope.

Answer (score 0):

just use 
[class_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) to make sure your class is there.